# Undefined when accessing property from json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a very simple JSON however, following code is not mapping required array from it.

Have converted json into array still i'm not able to get name.Please help me !!!

```
var info = [{"userDetails":[{"name":"Test","id":50,"gender":"m"}],"extraDetails":[{"errorMessage":null}],"moreInfo":{"totalDiscount":"0.0"},"errorCode":0}];


info.map(function(entry){
  console.log(entry);  //this gives above json 
      var userDetails = "userDetails";
        console.log('userDetails', entry.userDetails);  //says undefined
 });
```

I need to access info.userDetails.name How can I do it ?

I'm not sure where I exactly went wrong.

Comment: How can I get the name of the user ?

Comment: trying to use the `Array` method `Map()` on an `object` - need info on why you are using `map()`

Comment: Do you actually have JSON, as in a string, or do you have a javascript array with objects, there's a difference ?

Comment: Anyway, works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/9GxHd/

Comment: entry.userDetails.map(function(e) { console.log(e.name)}); # Test

Comment: You're sure you're just not looking for bracket notation, as in `entry[userDetails]`, to use the variable as a key. Your example is a little confusing as there actually is a key with the same name as the variable, but it still looks like you want to use brackets.

Answer (score 1):

<s>`info` is not an array you can not use map on it.</s>

Moreover if `map` was correctly applied on `Object.keys(info)`, `entry.userDetails` would always be `undefined` because `entry` is `userDetails` in one of the iterations.

### Maybe what you want is `info.map` and then `userDetails.map`

**UPDATE** (due to question's update)

```
info.map(function (pieceOfInfo) {
    pieceOfInfo.userDetails.map(function (user) {
        console.log(user.name);
    });
});
```

Comment: `info` looks ***a lot*** like an array to me ?

Comment: well you editted your original post didn't you ? I updated mine as well accordingly to yours

Comment: I misunderstood sorry you are not OP, but OP has updated his answer, first `info` was an object, you can check it in history.